# Help with an if else loop in python

Tags: python

Hi here is my problem. I have a program that calulcates the averages of data in columns.
Example

```
Bob
1
2
3
```

the output is

```
Bob
2
```

Some of the data has 'na's
So for Joe

```
Joe
NA
NA
NA
```

I want this output to be NA

so I wrote an if else loop

The problem is that it doesn't execute the second part of the loop and just prints out one NA. Any suggestions?

Here is my program:

```
with open('C://achip.txt', "rtU") as f:
    columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
    numRows = 0
    sums = [0] * len(columns)

    numRowsPerColumn = [0] * len(columns) # this figures out the number of columns

    for line in f:
        # Skip empty lines since I was getting that error before
        if not line.strip():
            continue

        values = line.split(" ")
        for i in xrange(len(values)):
            try: # this is the whole strings to math numbers things
                sums[i] += float(values[i])
                numRowsPerColumn[i] += 1
            except ValueError:
                continue 

    with open('c://chipdone.txt', 'w') as ouf:
        for i in xrange(len(columns)):
           if numRowsPerColumn[i] ==0 :
               print 'NA' 
           else:
               print>>ouf, columns[i], sums[i] / numRowsPerColumn[i] # this is the average calculator
```

The file looks like so:

```
Joe Bob Sam
1 2 NA
2 4 NA
3 NA NA
1 1  NA
```

and final output is the names and the averages

```
Joe Bob Sam 
1.5 1.5 NA
```

Ok I tried Roger's suggestion and now I have this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/avy14.py", line 5, in 
    for line in f:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Here is this new code:

with open('C://achip.txt', "rtU") as f:
  columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
  sums = [0] * len(columns)
rows = 0
for line in f:
  line = line.strip()
  if not line:
    continue

rows += 1
  for col, v in enumerate(line.split()):
    if sums[col] is not None:
      if v == "NA":
        sums[col] = None
      else:
        sums[col] += int(v)

with open("c:/chipdone.txt", "w") as out:
    for name, sum in zip(columns, sums):
        print >>out, name,
    if sum is None:
      print >>out, "NA"
    else:
      print >>out, sum / rows

Comment: Use "C:\\file" or "c:/file", with the latter usually preferred; Using "//" will be interpreted incorrectly in many cases (just not in this exact one).

Comment: Could you paste an example of what the source file looks like, and a sample of what the complete output should look like?

Comment: ...and also, could you include the code of the "second part of the loop"? The code provided only contains two alternative instructions (if/else)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("c:/achip.txt", "rU") as f:
  columns = f.readline().strip().split()
  sums = [0.0] * len(columns)
  row_counts = [0] * len(columns)

  for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
      continue

    for col, v in enumerate(line.split()):
      if v != "NA":
        sums[col] += int(v)
        row_counts[col] += 1

with open("c:/chipdone.txt", "w") as out:
  for name, sum, rows in zip(columns, sums, row_counts):
    print >>out, name,
    if rows == 0:
      print >>out, "NA"
    else:
      print >>out, sum / rows
```

I'd also use the no-parameter version of split when getting the column names (it allows you to have multiple space separators).

Regarding your edit to include input/output sample, I kept your original format and my output would be:

```
Joe 1.75
Bob 2.33333333333
Sam NA
```

This format is 3 rows of (ColumnName, Avg) columns, but you can change the output if you want, of course. :)

Comment: @Robert: The code you included in your edit is misindented with the for loop outside of the *with,* closing the file before the for loop runs.  Updated my code to show what I mean.

Comment: @Robert: I also see that the code I wrote (before you included the example) is wrong, as I misinterpreted you.  Fixed.

Comment: Still not working Roger. Now when i have a name like Joe 2 NA 1....the final value should be 1.5 and it outputs as NA

Comment: @Robert: Using 0.0 instead of 0 for sums (so floating point is used) and I get Joe 1.75, Bob 2.333.., Sam NA for the input sample you gave in the question.  These values match what I figure out by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

with open('achip.txt') as f:
    names=f.readline().split()
    arr=np.genfromtxt(f)

print(arr)
# [[  1.   2.  NaN]
#  [  2.   4.  NaN]
#  [  3.  NaN  NaN]
#  [  1.   1.  NaN]]

print(names)
# ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Sam']

print(np.ma.mean(np.ma.masked_invalid(arr),axis=0))
# [1.75 2.33333333333 --]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code, I would add one loop and edit the print statement

```
    with open(r'C:\achip.txt', "rtU") as f:
    columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
    numRows = 0
    sums = [0] * len(columns)

    numRowsPerColumn = [0] * len(columns) # this figures out the number of columns

    for line in f:
        # Skip empty lines since I was getting that error before
        if not line.strip():
            continue

        values = line.split(" ")

        ### This removes any '' elements caused by having two spaces like
        ### in the last line of your example chip file above
        for count, v in enumerate(values):      
            if v == '':     
                values.pop(count)
        ### (End of Addition)

        for i in xrange(len(values)):
            try: # this is the whole strings to math numbers things
                sums[i] += float(values[i])
                numRowsPerColumn[i] += 1
            except ValueError:
                continue 

    with open('c://chipdone.txt', 'w') as ouf:
        for i in xrange(len(columns)):
           if numRowsPerColumn[i] ==0 :
               print>>ouf, columns[i], 'NA' #Just add the extra parts
           else:
               print>>ouf, columns[i], sums[i] / numRowsPerColumn[i]
```

This solution also gives the same result in Roger's format, not your intended format.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below is cleaner and has fewer lines of code ...

```
import pandas as pd

# read the file into a DataFrame using read_csv
df = pd.read_csv('C://achip.txt', sep="\s+")

# compute the average of each column
avg = df.mean()

# save computed average to output file
avg.to_csv("c:/chipdone.txt")
```

They key to the simplicity of this solution is the way the input text file is read into a Dataframe. Pandas read_csv allows you to use regular expressions for specifying the sep/delimiter argument. In this case, we used the "\s+" regex pattern to take care of having one or more spaces between columns.

Once the data is in a dataframe, computing the average and saving to a file can all be done with straight forward pandas functions.